Is VertexAI Edge TFLite GPU Enabled?
I am running my TFLite model on mobile, using react-native-fast-tflite to handle the file for mobile app development.
I updated my config to enable CoreML:
 [
        'react-native-fast-tflite',
        {
          enableCoreMLDelegate: true,
        },
      ],

and then I try to import the file:
const modelData = useTensorflowModel(modelAsset, 'core-ml);

But the model loading fails, only if I have the core-ml delegate flag.
How do I know if the Edge model I trained & exported from VertexAI to TFLite is GPU enabled?
